# Declaring global class variables in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my class constructor, I declare some constants from navigation props. However, I cannot access these constants in the rest of my class. I could just make more variables `this.data = data` and `this.key = key`...but that would be rather redundant.

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    const { name, who, what, time, date, where, key } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
    this.date = date;
    this.key = key;
    this.state = {
      changed: false,
      saving: false,
      cancel: false,
      curTitle: name,
      curWho: who,
      curTime: time,
      curDate: date,
      curDescription: what,
      curWhere: where
    }
    console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Setting a timer'];
    console.log(this.date + " " + this.key);
  }
```

Comment: What is this? `console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Setting a timer'];`

Comment: What is `console.log(this.props.navigation.state)` in `render()`? You could also set `this.params = this.props.navigation.state.params` in `constructor` and then access `this.params.name`.

Comment: @AndrewLi The `console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Setting a timer'];` is to stop an android issue where it will constantly set timers when listening for new items from a database (I have firebase set up later in the code).

Comment: @tywoodpav Thanks for the suggestion. I adopted it! I didn't understand what you were asking about `console.log(this.props.navigation.state)'. That would just log all the parameters passed from the parent screen to this screen.

Comment: @vjd if you didnt want to use `this.params` you could just use `const { name,...} = this.props.navigation.state.params` in `render()` or wherever else you want to use them.

Comment: The error is that you are using `const` which gives those variable block scope, meaning they are variables that live only in their enclosing curly braces (in this case the constructor function)

Answer (score 2):

The vars are binded properly.

You probably have to bind the functions you want to access those vars:

```
....
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.something = 'foo';
  this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
}
doSomething() {
  console.log(this.something); // will show 'foo'
}
...
```

Hope this helps.